# Projection onto a closed convex set in a general Hilbert space

Tags: convex-analysis, hilbert-spaces, convex-geometry

Let $E$ denote a real Hilbert space and suppose $G \subset E$ is a nonempty closed convex set. I know that in this case, there is a unique nearest point in $G$ to each $x \in E$. Call this point $P_G(x)$.

I am trying to prove the following proposition:

> Let $\bar x \in E \setminus G$, and consider the hyperplane $H = \{x \in E : \langle x - P_G(\bar x), \bar x - P_G(\bar x)\rangle \leq 0\}$.Then $G \subset H$ but $\bar x \not \in H$.

It is clear that $\bar x \not \in H$, for else $\bar x = P_G(\bar x)$ and then $\bar x \in G$.

To show $G \subset H$, I came up with the following proof that works in $\mathbf{R}^d$, but I am not sure how to justify (e.g. the differentiation) in the setting of a Hilbert space.

Suppose that $x' \in G$ but $x' \not \in H$; hence $\langle x' - P_G(\bar x), \bar x - P_G(\bar x)\rangle > 0$. Consider the point
$$
x_t := P_G(\bar x) + t\big(x' - P_G(\bar x)\big), \quad t \in \mathbf{R}
$$
And also consider
$$
f(t) = \|x_t - \bar x\|^2 - \|P_G(\bar x) - \bar x\|^2
$$
Note that
$$
\dot{f}(t) = 2\Big\langle P_G(\bar x) - \bar x + t\big(x' - P_G(\bar x)\big), x' - P_G(\bar x)\Big\rangle
$$
In particular $\dot{f}(0) < 0$ by hypothesis. Therefore for some $0 < \tau < 1$, we see that $f(\tau) < f(0) = 0$. This implies that
$$
\|x_\tau - \bar x\| < \|P_G(\bar x) - \bar x\|,
$$
but on the other hand $x_\tau \in G$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Have you tried playing with the variational inequality characterization of $P_G(\overline{x})$?

Comment: @Zim I approve of all of your comments and am glad you post here.

Comment: Isn't that kind of what we are trying to prove here?

Comment: I suppose it's a little unclear what we're allowed to assume is already "done" and what is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p=P_G(\bar{x})$.

Since $\bar{x} \notin G$ you know that$  \|\bar{x}-p\| >0$.
Now note that $\langle \bar{x} - p, \bar x - p \rangle = \|\bar{x}-p\|^2 >0$ and so $\bar{x} \notin H$.

For any $x \in G$ we have $\|x-\bar{x}\|^2 = \|x-p+p-\bar{x}\|^2 \ge \|p-\bar{x}\|^2$,
and so$\|x-p\|^2 + 2 \langle x-p,p-\bar{x} \rangle \ge 0$ for all $x \in G$.

Replacing $x$ by $tx+(1-t)p$ with $t \in [0,1]$, we get
$t^2 \|x-p\|^2 + 2 t\langle x-p,p-\bar{x} \rangle \ge 0$ for all $x \in G$ and $t \in [0,1]$. Hence
$\langle x-p,p-\bar{x} \rangle \ge 0$ for all $x \in G$.

In particular, if $x \in G$ then $x \in H$.